# What is Yii 2.0 and what does it do?

Tags: yii2

How does Yii 2.0 work and what does it do?

I'm new to IT. I read the documentation online, but I don't understand what it does and how it works. Maybe the documentation is to advanced for me or my newbie head can't wrap around it.

Comment: That's kinda offtopic for Stackoverflow, though Yii is one of the PHP frameworks for developing web-applications.

Comment: Okay thanks @Bfcm Do you maybe know where I can find documentation about Yii 2.0 thats newby proof?

Comment: See my answer and if you think its okey - it would be nice to accept and thumb up it. Thanks.

Comment: Your internship managers should be teaching you this. That's the whole point of an internship - to learn from the company you're interning with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to mention, that Stack Overflow is not "Google for software developers". 95% of information could be found if you just google for it.

So if you are doing internship and has to do something with the Yii framework, I assume you already can do some PHP and probably know what is software development (web development). You can develop your web applications using different frameworks. One of those frameworks is the Yii framework.

There is a lot of information about the Yii on the [official Yii homepage](http://www.yiiframework.com/about/). You can start with reading its documentation.

Then there is also the "Definitive guide to Yii 2.0". Here is [introduction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-yii.html) and the [first steps](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html).

Have fun with learning it, and I wish you success learning Yii.

Comment: I agree with you. I used this as a last resort. Thanks a bunch for the info. I do have some knowledge of php. I never used frameworks though.